# L hospital rule

Tags: limits

I havent done this in a while but is my steps right?

$$=\lim_{A\to0^+} - ln(A)\frac{A^2}{2}$$

$$=\lim_{A\to0^+} -\frac{ln(A)}{2A^{-2}}$$ by L.H

$$=\lim_{A\to0^+} \frac{A}{4} = 0$$

Comment: $$-\dfrac{\dfrac1A}{2(-2)\dfarc1{A^3}}=\dfrac{A^2}4$$

Comment: oh thx i get it